# C++ dynamic_cast to subclass and trying to access to attribute

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have following Classes:

```
class Vehicle
{
public:
    Vehicle(int id);
    virtual int getID() const;
    virtual void setCustom(Customer* custom);
    virtual Customer *getCustom() const;
    virtual void printOnce() const = 0;
protected:
    int id_;
    Customer* custom_;
};


Vehicle::Vehicle(int id)
    : id_{id}, custom_{nullptr}
{

}

class Car : public Vehicle
{
public:
    Car(int id, int seats, string color);
    virtual void printOnce() const override;
private:
    int seats_;
    int color_;
};

Car::Car(int id, int seats, string color)
    : Vehicle(id), seats_{seats}, color_{color}
{

}

class Customer
{
public:
    Customer(string customerName, int age, int driverlicenceType);
    string getCustomerName() const;
private:
    string customerName_;
    int age_;
    int driverlicenceType_;
};

Customer::Customer(string customerName, int age, int driverlicenceType)
    : customerName_{customerName}, age_{age}, driverlicenceType_{driverlicenceType}
{

}

string Customer::getCustomerName() const
{
    return customerName_;
}
```

and the following Method:

```
Vehicle *CarRental::findByName(string name)
{
    auto cmp =[name](Vehicle* v){
        if(v->getCustom() != nullptr) {
            return name == v->getCustom()->getCustomerName();
        }
    };

    //find Vehicle in vector <Vehicle*> vehicles_;
    return (*find_if(vehicles_.begin(), vehicles_.end(), cmp));
}
```

Now I'm trying to get the `Vehicle*`, cast it to `Car*`, and test if the Customer is `nullptr`.

Code:

```
Vehicle* veh = findByName(name);
Car* c = dynamic_cast<Car*>(veh);

    if(c->getCustom() == nullptr) {
        //do anything
    }
```

But somehow it isn't `nullptr`. If I try to get the name or age:

```
cout << "Customer: " << c->getCustom() << endl;
```

it shows me only Customer: (like an empty string). I think if it were `nullptr` this should not work and give me an error but I don't know why.

Comment: `*find_if(vehicles_.begin(), vehicles_.end(), cmp)` attempt to dereference past the end iterator is undefined behavior. And `find_if` returns `vehicles_.end()` if the element is not found.

Comment: What purpose does the cast fulfil in your code? `getCustom` is a method of `Vehicle`, so you can (and should!) directly call `veh->getCustom()` without the cast. And in general `dynamic_cast` *only* makes sense if you immediately afterwards inspect the result of the cast (i.e. whether the cast was successful). That’s the only point of `dynamic_cast`. Don’t use it if you don’t do that.

Comment: Also, your lambda falls off the end (no `return` statement) if `v->getCustom()` returns a null pointer - so causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @pptaszni I don’t see it. The `find_if` looks fine to me. The issue is the comparator, which causes UB.

Comment: As a side note, don't forget to add a `virtual` destructor to the base class `Vehicle`. I.e. `virtual ~Vehicle() = default;`.

Comment: @pptaszni how make it right?

Comment: @KonradRudolph i need the cast to proove if the Vehicle at this position is a Car* to perform anything if its not a Car* the dynamic cast will return a nullptr as I know.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, comparator also causes UB, I didn't notice before. But even with good comparator, not checking for `if (result != vec.end())` is still UB if element does not exist in a vector.

Comment: @Nexxizz just check if the result of `find_if` is not `vehicles_.end()`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find even if you are sure that the element exist, it's a good practice, because maybe you will change your elements later.

Comment: something like this?
vector<Vehicle*>::iterator veh = find_if(vehicles_.begin(), vehicles_.end(), cmp);
    if(veh != vehicles_.end())
    return *veh;

Comment: @Nexxizz You’re *not* checking the result of `dynamic_cast` in your current code, so you don’t need the cast.

Comment: @pptaszni Ah yes, of course. I thought you meant the call itself was UB, instead of the lack of checking the result.

Comment: ah yes youre right in my Programm i also have if(!c) { //do anything }